# Is it correct to use the relative pronoun 'that' after the pronoun 'one'

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

from a band score 9 (the highest) IELTS essay:

'In conclusion, free university education is a must for any country that values equal rights and one that wishes to advance. The cost of free educ...'

Here 'one' refers to students I'm sure as the essay starts:

'(...) University education should be free as it will greatly benefit both individuals and society'.

So why is 'that' used for humans instead of 'who' ?

Comment: Why do you think "one" refers to students?  The sentence talks about *any country* and does not mention students.  (I also think it is a badly written sentence.)

Comment: ***one*** refers to ***any country***. But I agree with @stangdon it's poor quality writing. The words ***one that*** should simply be removed.

Comment: As well as the other points made, _that_ is not a relative pronoun. Ever. It is a subordinator, and can often be used instead of a relative pronoun (whether that is _who_, or _what_,)

Comment: In anything like '… country that values equal rights and one that wishes to advance…' the only thing to which 'one' might refer would be the country; never any students.

Answer (score 0):

'One' isn't only an impersonal pronoun - in fact, it is increasingly rare to use it as such, and is considered to be extremely formal.

'One' can also be a *determiner*, and in your example refers back to the previously mentioned 'any country', so it means *any one of the possible countries* in the scope of the statement.

So the sentence is fine as it is - but the word 'one' is something of a redundancy, and you could just write:

> free university education is a must for any country that values equal rights and that wishes to advance.

Comment: Actually, "one" is a common noun here, whose function is that of **head** of the NP "one that wishes to advance".